# Guava version conflict happens in spark-connector

Tags: graph-databases, nebula-graph

I met a problem when I use NebulaGraph Database like below：

I want to write offline spark data into NebulaGraph Database by spark-nebula-connector.

But I encountered two problems:

First, the NebulaGraph Database version I use only support spark v2.4 and scala v2.11. For this one, I solve it by downgrading the spark and scala version.

Second, spark connector writes data via client, but clients has strong dependence on guava-14：[nebula-java/pom.xml at v3.3.0 · vesoft-inc/nebula-java · GitHub](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-java/blob/v3.3.0/client/pom.xml#L20)
And my spark also has strong dependence on guava，guava-27.0-jre

If I use guava-27.0, it will give `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError (com.google.common.net.HostAndPort.getHostText()`

If I use guava-14.0, EROOR will be give when the spark reads hive, like `Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument`

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can refer this solution. Guava-14.0 and Guava-27.0 of the HostAndPort have different methods to acqure hosts. You can change the Guava version in connector or exchange, modify the HostAndPort.getHostTex, and then package it locally.